# LARAVEL 5 How to store empty DateTime input to Null value instead of 0000:00:00 00:00 value

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i had two input Datetime field. 
User can choose to fill in either these two field. 
For the empty input Datetime field, i want it to store as Null value in Database. 
But currently the empty input Datetime field is store as 0000:00:00 00:00 value in Database. What code should i modified?

Answer (score 0):

you can use model observers to unset the attribute before saving when it is empty. But be sure that the fields are nullable

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::saving(function ($flight_model) {

            if(empty($flight_model->arriveDateTime)) unset($your_model->attributes['your_date_field1'];
            if(empty($flight_model->departDateTime)) unset($your_model->attributes['your_date_field2'];

        });

    }
}
```

[this discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-pass-default-to-null) would be a good reference

**Update**
to do the limitation in the controller you'll use [`required_without_all:foo,bar,...`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-without-all) which as described in doc.s

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when all of the other specified fields are not present
>   to use it we'll add new rules like

```
$rules = array(
    'arriveDateTime' => 'required_without_all:departDateTime',
    'departDateTime' => 'required_without_all:arriveDateTime',
);
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

and if you're using rules already just append this two roles to them. that's for the controller validation part.

for the view part I'll assume you've two inputs with `id="arriveDateTime"` and `id="departDateTime"` the code would be like

```js
$(function() {
  <!-- if the first input value changed disable the second input -->
  $('#arriveDateTime').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $('#departDateTime').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $('#departDateTime').prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });

  <!-- if the second input value changed disable the first input -->
  $('#departDateTime').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $('#arriveDateTime').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $('#arriveDateTime').prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="arriveDateTime" />
<input type="text" id="departDateTime" />
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, but it still not very clear to me. This is my Flight Model which contain arriveDateTime, departDateTime, destination and remark fields. User are allowed to fill in either arriveDateTime or departDateTime. So how to code it in my Flight model?  class Flight extends Model{...}??

Comment: you don't have a model yet ?

Comment: What does it mean by i don't have a model yet? i have the Flight Model. i am using Laravel 5.3

Comment: short answer is no do it in controller and views.

Comment: what's mentioned in the first comment is a logic which nothing to do with data as data. it's about how to control the user's behavior which I'd do it in the views using JS to allow the user to fill only one field by disabling the other field. and to validate that data in the controller too.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your comment. But it is still not very clear to me, It will be good if you have the sample coding to show. Thanks

Comment: that's alright but I'll need to know in your `store` function in controller. do you use `Validator` or can you use it ?

Comment: ya i did use Validator. I would like to show u my store function coding. Can i send the code to your email to have a look? because pasting the code here will exceed the character value

Comment: @JovenDev any news ?

Comment: hi @M.Elwan i haven't try it, but the code you added had gave me some idea on solving other issue. Can you help in looking on this issue too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341798/laravel-5-how-to-validate-a-unique-customer-name-under-each-activity-when-save

Answer (score 0):

All you need is **Eloquent Mutators**.

Below a simplified example, basically from https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

```
class User extends Model
{
    /* Set or mutate value of property */
    public function setDateInputAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['date_input'] = $this->dateTimeOrNull($value);
    }

    /* This method should get another place, because it's not the core of this model */
    private function dateTimeOrNull($value)
    {
        /* 
           Check if given datetime is valid. Yes? Return original $value
           For simplicity, I use PHP's DateTime class
        */
        if (DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value) !== false) {
            return $value;
        }

        /* Datetime is not valid. Return null */
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Further

I suppose your datetime format is like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss`

Answer (score 0):

You can uses laravel mutators. Here's one for date of birth.

```js
 public function setDob($value)
    {
       $this->attributes['dob'] = strlen($value)?            Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value) : null;
        
    }
```

Comment: This is a not the correct mode for a mutator on Laravel instead must be setDobAttribute($value)